# Changing the LESS build path in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

In Cloud9 IDE, I can create a file called `styles.less` and write some LESS styles in it. Then, I can do `Ctrl+B` to build it into a CSS file. Cloud9 does this by creating a file called `styles.css` in the same directory.

However, what I want to be able to do is have LESS files in `less/` be compiled into CSS files in `css/` instead. So, `less/styles.less` would compile into `css/styles.css` when I do `Ctrl+B`

There's nothing in the GUI, but is there a settings file I can edit to change the way that compiles happen? I've Googled this but there seem to be several ways of installing, setting up and using LESS in Ubuntu, and I have no idea which one of these methods is being used behind the scenes when I press `Ctrl+B` in Cloud9.

**Edit:** I'd also like to be able to add the -x option to minify the output but, again, I don't know where to put this. I like the convenience of just doing `Ctrl+B` and don't want to have to type out a full `lessc` command each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new LESS builder, based on the default one, to suit your needs. Check out the Cloud9 doc [here](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/custom-runners) that talks about customer runners/builders. The code for the default LESS builder is:

```
{
    "caption" : "LESS",
    "cmd": ["lessc", "$file", ">", "${file/\\.less/\\.css/}"],
    "selector": "source.less"
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I accomplished what I wanted with the "cmd" of `"lessc", "-x", "$file", "${file/\\less/css/}"` which compresses the output and outputs to the css directory.

Comment: One note to anyone else trying this: When you add a new builder (via Run | Build System | New Build System) the builder you create will only work the first time you save it. After that, for subsequent edits, you'll need to refresh the Cloud9 environment (via a browser refresh) to get it to notice the changes you've made.

Comment: Also, creating a replacement LESS builder doesn't seem to override the built-in one as the Custom Runner docs suggest. Therefore, I had to manually select my custom builder in "Run | Build System" to stop it from using the built in one.